# Manual vs. automated testing on large project with a small team (and little time)

Tags: testing, process, automated-tests

I work in a small development team consisting of 5 programmers, of which none have any overall testing experience. The product we develop is a complex VMS, basically consisting of a (separate) video server and a client for viewing live and recorded video. Since video processing requires a lot of hardware power, the software is typically deployed on multiple servers.

We use a slimmed down version of feature driven development. Over the past few months a lot of features were implemented, leaving almost no time for the luxury of QA.

I'm currently researching a way for us to test our software as (time) efficient as possible. I'm aware of software methodologies build around testing, such as TDD. However, since many features are built around the distributed architecture, it is hard to write individual tests for individual features. Given that many of the features require some of the endless scenarios is which it can be deployed to be replicated in order to be tested properly.

For example, recently we developed a failover feature, in which one or more idle server will monitor other servers, and take its place in case of failure. Likely scenarios will include failover servers in a remote location or different subnet, or multiple failing servers at a time.

Manually setting up these scenarios takes a lot of valuable time. Even though I'm aware that manual initialization will always be required in this case, I cannot seem to find a way in which we can automate these kinds of tests (preferably defining them before implementing the feature) without having to invest an equal or greater amount of time in actually creating the automated tests.

Does anyone have any experience in a similar environment, or can tell me more about (automated) testing methodologies or techniques which are fit for such an environment? We are willing to overthrow our current development process if it enhances testing in a significant way.

Thanks in advance for any input. And excuse my grammar, as English not my first language :)

Comment: I think part of the problem you face, is captured in this sentence: "... leaving almost no time for the luxury of QA." If you view QA as something to be added on later, then you are setting yourselves up for a world of pain.

Comment: What I described below, is what I have implemented in my last two jobs and what I have helped others to deploy. I was working with software as complex, if not more complex, as what you are building and deploying. If you would like to discuss things further contact me directly.

Comment: I wonder if this a good fit for programmers.stackexchange.com than here?

Comment: You are correct that this might be a better fit at programmers.stackexchange.com, given that it is more about practice than about having a specific solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I approach test strategy by thinking of layers in a pyramid.

The first layer in the pyramid are your unit tests. I define unit tests as tests that exercise a single method of a class. Each and every class in your system should have a suite of tests associated with it. And each and every method should have a set of tests in included in that suite. These tests can and should exist in a mocked environment.

This is the foundation of testing and quality strategy. If you have solid test coverage here, a lot of issues will be nipped in the bud. These are the cheapest and easiest of all the tests you will be creating. You can get a tremendous bang for your buck here.

The next layer in the pyramid are your functional tests. I define functional tests as tests that exercise the classes in a module. This is where you are testing how various classes interact with one another. These tests can and should exist in a mocked environment.

The next layer up are your integration tests. I define integration tests as tests that exercise the interaction between modules. This is where you are testing how various modules interact with one another. These tests can and should exist in a mocked environment.

The next layer up is what I call behavioral or workflow tests. These are tests which exercise the system as would a customer. These are the most expensive and hardest tests to build and maintain, but they are critical. They confirm that the system works as a customer would expect it to work.

The top of your pyramid is exploratory testing. This is by definition a manual activity. This is where you have someone who knows how to use the system take it through its paces and work to identify issues. This is to a degree an art and requires a special personality. But it is invaluable to your overall success.

What I have described above, is just a part of what you will need to do. The next piece is setting up a Continuous Integration/Continuous Deployment (CI/CD) pipeline.

Whenever code is committed to one of your repos, and I do hope that you have a project as big as this broken up into separate repos, that component should undergo static analysis (i.e. lint it), be built, have tests executed against it, have code coverage data gathered.

Just the act of building each component of your system regularly, will help to flush out issues. Combine that with running unit/functional/integration tests against it and you are going to be identifying a lot of issues.

Once you have built a component, you should deploy it into a test or staging environment. This process must be automated and able to run unattended. I highly recommend you consider using [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/) from [Opscode](http://www.opscode.com/) for this process.

Once you have it deployed in a staging or test environment, you can start hitting it with workflow and behavioral tests.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this model. It is comprohensive yet implementable in steps. Also, I'm confident that the design of our software allows for module-based testing. I will certainly investigate how this model can be applied within our development process.

Comment: Oh, just one more thing. I've worked with intergration and workflow tests before. However, unit testing is very vague to me. Can you recommend a resource which explains the practice and depth of unit tests?

Comment: @Thijs - Ping me directly (my linkedin is in my SO profile) and we can discuss this. Perhaps we can identify several solid SO question-answers and then build them.

Answer (score 0):

I approach testing first by:

- choosing P0/P1 test cases for functional and automated testing
- choosing what framework I will use and why
- getting tools and framework setup while doing testing manually for releases
- build an MVP, at lease automating high priority test cases
- after building a test suite of regression test cases that run on a daily basis.

Main thing is you have to start with MVP.